# Is there any way to put an .exe application on an iPhone or blackberry

Tags: iphone, blackberry, exe

I am working for Bentley leathers and I we have a password calculator (.exe) and I am wondering if I could put it on my iPhone or the compagny BlackBerry so that way it would be easier then to have a ton of paper with me.

Comment: If you manage to install any version of windows on a iPhone or BlackBerry you can run the exe. =)) 
P.S: You can write a native app that will do the job.

Comment: This is not a programming question . . .

Answer (score 3):

No since the operating systems are not windows, why don't you create a password protected website with the same functionality so that you can access that from any device with a browser

Comment: Is there any way to transform the .exe so it can run on something else than windows ?

Comment: I think .exe generates session password for website/intranet

Comment: On a real computer running Mac or Linux you could run it in a virtual machine or possibly run it with WINE but you're not going to get it to run on a phone.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you mean a Windows .exe, no you can't, the iPhone and Blackberry apps run off their own operating systems.

Answer (score 2):

I think yes on the iPhone, but it requires it to be jailbroken.
There used to be a program called iDos of Dosbox (i thing Dosbox) on the app store, It was removed because you could upload, download and run exe files directly from the app (to get the exe's you used that itunes file sharing thing used in those flash drive apps).

They released it as Idos for about a day of 2 but than got deleted (i have no idea why im talking about idos).

Final Answer...

in the new idos (again deleted), they got rid of the ability to run exe's, but if you got the first version of it called "DOSBOX" on cydia, you could probally run some simple exe's on your iPhone (you could also use installous or use app sync to get a cracked .ipa file of Dosbox.
NOTE: I have not tested this! all i know is that when i saw the newer version on dosbox (Idos) on the top 25 list in the app store, i got it. I google searched on how to get more games for it and all these sites had all this "RETURN OD DOSBOX!!!" stuff.
I then read you could us exe's on the original.

Answer (score 1):

Get Portable .NET from http://ininjas.com/repo/

It lets you run Windows .NET exe files from within mobileterminal. To run:

```
clrwrap program.exe
```

To compile C# files:

```
cscc -o output.exe code.cs
```

Original post (by me):
http://ininjas.com/forum/index.php?topic=84.0

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that password calculator is a software to generate session passwords for the intranet/vpn/whatever.

You can't launch it on Blackberry or on iPhone but your company can order development of this tool for someone and after that distribute it inside the company. I know at least one company who already did it for iPhone. You can order this development. For sure a lot of people will be glad to do that (bu you should go to the Jobs section with this offers). But developer will need a specification with description of password generation.